# For Loop: LED's Will Not Display Correctly on Arduino

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, arduino

Here is the code so far:

```
bool t1 = true;
bool f1 = false;
bool button_state = 0;
int delay_led = 100;
int led_num = 1, buzzer_delay = 75;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(2, INPUT); pinMode(10, OUTPUT); pinMode(11, OUTPUT); 
pinMode(12, OUTPUT); pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalRead(2);
button_state = digitalRead(2);

if (button_state == 0)
{
  for (led_num = 10; led_num <= 13; led_num++)
  {
  digitalWrite(led_num, t1);
  delay(delay_led);
  digitalWrite(led_num, f1);
  }
}

else
{
    for (led_num >= 10; led_num <= 13; led_num++)
  {
  digitalWrite(led_num, t1);
  }
}
}
```

I'm trying to get the LEDs to light up at once, which is what the else statement is used for. However, our instructor specifically stated to use loops to accomplish this. Here is our assignment:

[Here is an image of our assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7oIE.png)

I cannot figure out how to use loops instead on the if/else and I cannot get the LEDs to light up at once. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need an outside loop that runs forever and keeps polling the button state....

Your else doesn't need a loop, it just needs to turn all the lights on, wait, then turn them all off.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `foor` loop *init-statement* of `led_num >= 10` is wrong as it has no effect. Instead of:

```
for (led_num >= 10; led_num <= 13; led_num++)
```

it should probably be:

```
for (led_num = 11; led_num <= 13; led_num++)
```

Comment: Thanks, Ron! I upvoted your answer, but apparently, users under a certain level do not publically affect the answers upvotes.